# Not able to change boolean property in domain class through beforeInsert event

Tags: grails

I have this domain class:

```
class Pet {
  String name
  String type
  Boolean status = true

  static constraints = {
    name blank:false
    type inList:["Dog", "Cat"]
  }

  def beforeInsert() {
    status = (type == "Dog") ? true : false
  }

  String toString() { name }
}
```

I want to use the `beforeInsert` event to change a boolean property based on a condition.

I try to create a some test data in `bootstrap.groovy`:

```
class BootStrap {
  def init = { servletContext ->
    def nami = new Pet(name:"nami", type:"Dog")

    if (!nami.save()) {
     nami.errors.allErrors.each { error ->
        log.error "[$error.field: $error.defaultMessage]"
    }
   }

   def hotch = new Pet(name:"hotch", type:"Cat")

   if (!hotch.save()) {
      hotch.errors.allErrors.each { error ->
        log.error "[$error.field: $error.defaultMessage]"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

But when I run `grails run-app` (using grails 2.3.8) I get this error message:

```
| Error 2014-10-07 13:27:28,281 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR conf.BootStrap  - [status:  Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
| Error 2014-10-07 13:27:28,314 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR conf.BootStrap  - [status: Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
```

`beforeInsert` appears to fine if there are no boolean properties.

What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

By definition `beforeInsert` will cancel the operation if you return false at the end.

```
beforeInsert - Executed before an object is initially persisted to the database. 
               If you return false, the insert will be cancelled.
```

Since your `beforeInsert` method has only one line and it is setting the status to true or false, groovy will return that boolean value. If that happens to be false, it will cancel your save. You might want to return true or something other than false to avoid cancellation.

```
def beforeInsert() {
    status = (type == "Dog")
    true
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alidad, but i am getting the same error message even when i return true from beforeInsert. I set all type properties to Dog in objects in bootstrap in order to always status have to be set to true but no success